# ASP.NET MVC page with multiple forms and classes of a model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page in ASP.NET dedicated to role management. Administrators can add users to a role, create new roles, edit their respective names and delete them.

In the page, I need to call `@ModelType AdminModel.AddRole`, `@ModelType IEnumerable(Of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole)`, and other models.

However, MVC apparently doesn't allow me to do this.

> What other solutions do I have to display data and have multiple forms in the same page?

Comment: you really want multiple forms ?

Comment: Create a view model with properties for each 'sub model' Or use `@Html.Action()` to call methods that return partial views for each model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display some data and at the same time want a form to add a new record, you should create a new view model for this view and bind your view to that.

```
Public Class AddNewRoleVm

    Public Property NewRoleName As String

    Public Property RoleList As List(Of IdentityRole)
End Class
```

And your view will be like

```
@ModelType AddNewRoleVm

@Using Html.BeginForm()

    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.NewRoleName)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.NewRoleName)

    @:<input type = "submit" />
End Using

<h1>Existing Roles</h1>
@For Each role In Model.RoleList
    @:<h2>@role.Name</h2>
Next
```

Comment: I like the idea, I'm testing what I understood from this and will mark as answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, what I managed to do is create a `Public Class` which contained a Property for every model, and then called upon the Property to use the intended model.